# Merging multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I try to merge multidimensional arrays to one. I was using `array_merge` function but it does not work.

Look bellow at the arrays

```
$arr1 = [['title' => 'first title', 'phone' => '9923490', 'address' => 'thes 38'], ['title' => 'second title', 'phone' => '42342', 'address' => '2th thes 38 aradippou']];
$arr2 = [['town' => 'london'], ['town' => 'manchester']];


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => first title
            [phone] => 9923490
            [address] => thes 38 aradippou
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => second title
            [phone] => 42342
            [address] => 2th thes 38 aradippou
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [town] => london
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [town] => manchester
        )

)
```

I want to add the town fields to the $arr1 so it looks like as below array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => first title
            [phone] => 9923490
            [address] => thes 38 aradippou
            [town] => london
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => second title
            [phone] => 42342
            [address] => 2th thes 38 aradippou
            [town] => manchester
        )

)
```

I've try the `array_merge` function but the result is like thus:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => first title
            [phone] => 9923490
            [address] => thes 38 aradippou
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => second title
            [phone] => 42342
            [address] => 2th thes 38 aradippou
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [town] => london
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [town] => manchester
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using [union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

```
$newArray = array();
  for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++){
  $newArray[] = $arr1[$i]+$arr2[$i];
}
print_r($newArray);
```

with foreach

```
$newArray = array();
  foreach($arr1 as $k=>$val){
  $newArray[] = $arr1[$k]+$arr2[$k];
}
print_r($newArray);
```

This will give you your desired result as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [town] => london
            [title] => first title
            [phone] => 9923490
            [address] => thes 38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [town] => manchester
            [title] => second title
            [phone] => 42342
            [address] => 2th thes 38 aradippou
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) as below :

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value){
    $out[] = array_merge($arr2[$key], $value);
}
print_r($out);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [town] => london
            [title] => first title
            [phone] => 9923490
            [address] => thes 38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [town] => manchester
            [title] => second title
            [phone] => 42342
            [address] => 2th thes 38 aradippou
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

This function should do what you are after...

```
function array_merge_multi()
{
    $result = array();

    $args = func_get_args();
    if (is_array($args) && count($args) > 0) {
        foreach ($args as $arg) {
            for ($x = 0; $x < count($arg); $x++) {
                if (! array_key_exists($x, $result)) {
                    $result[$x] = array();
                }
                foreach ($arg[$x] as $key => $val) {
                    $result[$x][$key] = $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$x = array(
    array('name' => 'Tom', 'age' => 22),
    array('name' => 'Amelia', 'age' => 20),
);

$y = array(
    array('email' => 'tom@test.com'),
    array('email' => 'amelia@test.com'),
);

$z = array_merge_multi($x, $y);

/*
* var_dump($z);
* 
* gives....
* 
* $z = array(
*   array('name' => 'Tom', 'age' => 22, 'email' => 'tom@test.com'),
*   array('name' => 'Amelia', 'age' => 20, 'email' => 'amelia@test.com'),
* );
*/
```

Comment: Please add a comment providing an improvement or a reason when you down-vote an answer. I don't see a problem with this answer. It provides a re-usable function to merge multiple arrays into 1 which is what was asked for.